# Why use index signature `{[key: string]: any}` instead of `object` type?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and come across this use of index signatures in function parameters often. For eg,

```
export function template(resources: {[key: string]: any})
```

Since the value type is `any`, why is this type useful? And is it any different than passing `object` as the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to express 'objects', but consider the following examples. There is `Object`, `object`, `{}`, `{ [k: T]: U }` and `Record<K, T>`. This is just because almost everything in JS (and by extension TS) is an object.*

I'll put the answer up-front with examples below:

- `Object` means any non-nullish value
- `object` means any non-primitive
  value
- `{}` is the same as `Object`
- `{ [k: string]: any }` is equivalent to `Record<string, any>`
- `Record<K, T>` is a utility type to create mapped types. Often used for as a substitute for index signatures with `Record<string, any>` (shown above). Also can prescribe exact key/value pairs with something like `Record<'foo' | 'bar', 'baz' | 'bang'>` being equivalent to `{ bar: "baz" | "bang"; foo: "baz" | "bang"; }`
- To type an empty object, it is recommended to use `Record<string, never>`
- To type any object, you should use `Record<string, unknown>` or `Record<string, any>`
- To type any value, you should use `unknown` or `any`

#### Examples

Consider the following about `Object`:

```js
class C {}
const a: Object = 0
const b: Object = ""
const c: Object = []
const d: Object = {}
const e: Object = C
const f: Object = null // <-- error!
const g: Object = undefined // <-- error!
const h: Object = { foo: "bar" }
h.bar // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Consider the following about `object`:

```js
class C {}
const a: object = 0 // <-- error!
const b: object = "" // <-- error!
const c: object = []
const d: object = {}
const e: object = C
const f: object = undefined // <-- error!
const g: object = null // <-- error!
const h: object = { foo: "bar" }
h.bar // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

#### Relevant Docs

Read about [Record<K, T>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

Read about [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

versus [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

Comment: Not everything in JS is an object. number, strings, boolean, functions are not objects.

Comment: @RaduDiță My mistake, I clarified that 'almost' everything is an object. I believe the examples describe this behavior adequately (and we'd be straying too off-topic). As an aside: the distinction between object and Object follows similarly  between string and String (and I think it shows excellently why this behavior came to be in TS).

Comment: The reason I made the comment is that if everything would be an object then there would be some methods that can be used on any JS value. Which is not true and can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The `object` type is just a native js `Object`. It only has the functions and keys associated with the native `Object`.

So if you try to access a property of an `object` type, it will throw an error.

```js
let b: object = {foo: 123};
b.foo; // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'object'.(
```

But you can do the same with `{[key: string]: any}`

```
let a: {[key: string]: any} = {foo: 123};
a.foo;
```

You can do the same with `Record<string, any>`.

In fact, the `Record` type is declared as `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }`